# compare 2 arrays to see if objects exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, javascript-objects

**Array 1** = [object]

**Array 2** = [object, object]

Let's say in **array 1** object is :

```
 {
   'name': 'apple',
   'id': ''
 }
```

**and in array 2:**

object1:

```
 {
  'name': 'bananna',
  'id': 2
 }
```

object 2:

```
 {
  'name': 'apple',
  'id': 1
 }
```

I want to see if the object in array 1 is in array 2, and if it is, set array1's id to the same id. It should return true or the object itself, and then in array 1, the id should be changed to 1.

Don't think my attempt is fast. btw Both arrays can be any size.

```
  var itemFrom1;
  for (var a = 0; a < array1.length; a++) {
    itemFrom1 = array1[a];

    for(var b = 0; b < array2.length; b++) {                               
      if (itemFrom1.name === array2[b].name) {
        itemFrom1.id = array2[b].id;
      }
    }
  }
```

Maybe I could use underscore.js or an easier way.

```
var matched=_.findWhere(array2,{name:array1.name})
```

Note: need this to work for all browsers.

Comment: What's that stray dollar sign doing there?

Comment: you are checking equal indicies ... that is, you are checking if your first element of array1 has the same name as the first element of array2. Then you will be checking if the 2nd element matches the 2nd element, and so on.

Comment: @JimNastos yeah I realized, so how do I fix it,  because my approach is wrong. the indices can be different

Comment: As Jim says, you need two nested loops, not one loop. For every element in A, you need to compare it against every element in B.

Comment: @JosephYoung like so?

Comment: @Angular Almost, typo in `if(array1[a].name === array1[b].name)`, second value needs to be `array2`

Comment: The two `for-loops` are quite ok, its the fastest way of doing it, I think.

Comment: To improve performance, you should add a `break` in the second loop, to not waste time.. see my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

What it does is go through every element in `list1`, checks the name against every element in `list2`, and adds the ids of the matched ones in.

```js
var list1 = [
  { name: "apple" },
  { name: "grape" },
  { name: "orange" },
  { name: "watermelon" }
];
var list2 = [
  { name: "apple", id: 1 },
  { name: "grapefruit", id: 2 },
  { name: "grape", id: 3 }
];

for(item in list1) {
  var match = list2.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.name == list1[item].name;
  })[0] || false;
  if(match)
    list1[item].id = match.id;
}

console.log(list1);
```

---

In response to your request, I [tested both of ours on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jk2kx5wc/1/) and realized that mine was *much* slower (0.3799999999999386ms instead of 0.07999999999998408ms, according to `performance.now()`). Oops.

Yours works and is probably as straightforwards as you can get. I'd say stick with it.

Comment: dont you need to define id in list 1? and also, so this will set grape to id 2 and apple to id 1, in list 1 right?

Comment: also, is this faster than the 2 for loops I have now?

Comment: @Angular You don't need to have the `id` property defined in `list1` unless you want a sort of default value in case there isn't a match in `list2`. And yes, `grape`'s id will be set to 2 and `apple`'s to 1 (you can see this by running the snippet).

Comment: In terms of speed, @Angular, I'm not sure of the speed differences. I'll check that out now.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a hash table for the elements of `list1` and use it as a reference for adding the `id`. This proposal has a complexity of **O(n + m)**.

```js
var list1 = [{ name: "apple" }, { name: "grape" }, { name: "orange" }, { name: "watermelon" }],
    list2 = [{ name: "apple", id: 1 }, { name: "grapefruit", id: 2 }, { name: "grape", id: 3 }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

list1.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.name] = a;
});

list2.forEach(function (a) {
    if (hash[a.name]) {
        hash[a.name].id = a.id;
    }
});

console.log(list1);
```

Or use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), if your user agent support it.

```js
var list1 = [{ name: "apple" }, { name: "grape" }, { name: "orange" }, { name: "watermelon" }],
    list2 = [{ name: "apple", id: 1 }, { name: "grapefruit", id: 2 }, { name: "grape", id: 3 }],
    map = new Map();

list1.forEach(a => map.set(a.name, a));
list2.forEach(a => (map.get(a.name) || {}).id = a.id);

console.log(list1);
```

Comment: Why using hash object not hash Map? Is that for compatibility?

Comment: @mortezaT, actually `Object` is more reliable than `Map`.

Comment: Your answer is too broad. If you have any answer which you explained this can you send the link please?

Comment: @mortezaT, please view https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility

Comment: map compatibility is not too [bad](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Map).

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is ok, I would just add a `break;` to the second loop when the item was found in array2, otherwise you will iterate over all other items in array2, imagine the item you are looking for is the first one, you would iterate over the next N, if you don't break the second `for-loop`

```
  var itemFrom1;
  for (var a = 0; a < array1.length; a++) {
    itemFrom1 = array1[a];

    for(var b = 0; b < array2.length; b++) {                               
      if (itemFrom1.name === array2[b].name) {
        itemFrom1.id = array2[b].id;
        break; // Stops the second loop, go on with the next value from array1!
      }
    }
  }
```